# How to add separator option in Form API 'select' element?

Tags: forms

Is there a way with the Form API to specify that one or more *#options* in a 'select' element should be disabled? I would like to insert a separator in my dropdown options that is not a selectable value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's really a separator you're looking to add then it might make more semantic sense to use `<optgroup>`s to group your select options.

You can do this with the form API simply by wrapping each group you want in the `<select>` in an array, keyed by the title you want for the label:

```
$form['test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'test',
  '#weight' => -10000,
  '#options' => array(
    'Group 1' => array(
      1 => 'Group 1 Item 1'
    ),
    'Group 2' => array(
      2 => 'Group 2 Item 1',
      3 => 'Group 2 Item 2'
    )
  )
);
```

That will produce a select list like this:

[image: Select List]